# Entity-attribute-value mode or JSON in database?

Tags: c++, database-design

I have a database  schema where attribute are unlimited, I can have this structure using two ways.

1. Using Entity  attribute-value model

**table 1**

id 
entity

**table 2** 
entityid 
attribute-name 
attribute-value

2 . Way is to use JSON.

like 
table1 
id 
entity

```
json-attribute {"name":"value-pair"}
```

I have a question which way will be best and effective .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had chosen json solution. 
why ?

1. It will avoid writing complex query to fetch data.

What about if I need to load any particular attribute ?

1. yes. In JSON solution I have to load all attribute from the database.  and then filter for that particular attribute.

But in my case I will be loading all attribute every time.

If I have a condition of loading particular attribute I might have chosen attribute value schema.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with a DBMS that would let you *efficiently* find all entities where someAttribute = x, if the entities were stored in a non-deconstructed canonical JSON representation. (But I would be eager to know about any.)

The first approach using two tables (at least) can accomplish this task, and it is therefore the more capable and  the more flexible approach; a JSON representation of the entity always be constructed from the database recordset:

```
       // all entities having a particular attribute

       select entityid, attributeName, attributeValue
       from ENTITIES INNER JOIN ENTITYATTRIBUTES
       on ENTITY.ID = ENTITYATTRIBUTES.entityid
       where ENTITIES.id IN 
        (

          select distinct entityid from ENTITYATTRIBUTES
          where attributename = ? and attributeValue = ?

        )
```

OR

```
        // the attributes for a specified entity

       select attributeName, attributeValue
       from ENTITIES INNER JOIN ENTITYATTRIBUTES
       on ENTITY.ID = ENTITYATTRIBUTES.entityid
       where ENTITIES.id = ?
```

Complexity could enter, of course, if attributes could themselves contain entities. Nesting of objects is possible in the JSON representation but in the database it requires either a multi-table relational mapping or an OODBMS that supports nested tables.